# Особенности полиморфизма

Tags: java, jvm, полиморфизм

Всем доброго времени суток.

Только начал готовиться к собеседованию на **Java Junior`а**, как произошло небольшое недопонимание по поводу **полиморфизма**. Я изучал **Java Core** по книге **Кэти Сьерра и Берта Бейтса("Изучаем Java. 2-е издание")**.

Там механизм наследования (и вообще хранения объектов в *куче JVM*) представлялся вот так:

```
public class A{
//code...
}

public class B extends A{
//code...
}

public class TestApp{

public void init(){
B val = new B();
}

}
```

И в JVM это все выглядит таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Допустим, у нас есть такой код:

```
public class Animal{

public void makeSomthing(){
System.out.println("Animal"); 
} 

}


public class Dog extends Animal{

//переопределенный метод
@Override
public void makeSomthing(){
System.out.println("Dog");
} 

public void fMagic(){

this.makeSomthing(); //Console: Dog    
super.makeSomthing(); //Console: Animal [?]   

}

}


public class TestApp{

public static void main(String[] args){

Dog dogPet = new Dog();

dogPet.fMagic();

}

}
```

Выходит, что при вызове метода `fMagic()` у объекта `dogPet` так же вызывается метод `makeSomthing()` у **"внешнего"** объекта `Dog` и еще этот же метод вызывается у **"внутреннего"** объекта `Animal`(у суперкласса). Как я понял, по логике этой книги, конструкция переопределения(`@Override`) методов заключается в том, что метод по сути один, а когда мы его переопределяем, то как-бы изменяем его во **"внутреннем"** объекте c помощью **"внешнего"**. А уже при вызове `dogPet.fMagic()` он вызывается изнутри.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом:

класс `Dog`

```
   public void fMagic(){

    this.makeSomthing(); //Console: Dog
    super.makeSomthing(); //Console: Animal [?]

    //Console:  Dog@74a14482 -  адрес Dog. Dog@74a14482 - адрес Animal. 
    System.out.println("links:"+"\n" + this + " -  адрес Dog. "+ super.getObjectLink() + " - адрес Animal.");

}
```

класс `Animal`

```
 public Object getObjectLink(){ return this; }
```

Но самое странное на мой взгляд заключается вот в этом:
При сужении типа до его родителя, вызов функции дает "Dog", а не "Animal". Т.е в данном случае, переопределение метода в классе `Dog` изменяет метод `saySomthing()`. А вот в случае вызова метода `fMagic()` у класса `Dog`, вызываются 2 разные функции И переопределение функции суперкласса, как я понимаю, ничего не дает.

```
 Animal dogPet = new Dog();

 dogPet.makeSomthing(); //Console: Dog
```

**Суть вопроса:** *Как же именно все эти процессы и механизмы ООП происходят на самом деле? И почему же при вызове `fMagic()` на консоль выводится две разные надписи "Dog" и "Animal", а не одна и та же надпись "Dog", как в случае с `Animal dogPet = new Dog();`?*

Comment: Таблица виртуальных функций? Я про последний вопрос почему 2 разные надписи. Rti или как-то так вроде бы

Comment: @pavel Прошу прощения, я вас не совсем понял.

Comment: В c++ был бы вызван метод объекта Animal, и было бы напечатано 'Animal'. Если бы метод только не был объявлен виртуальным, и тогда всё было бы точно так же.
В java все методы виртуальные, всегда.

Comment: `Animal dogPet = new Dog();
 dogPet.makeSomthing(); //Console: Dog`
А `dogPet.fMagic();`  - и выведет сообщение как самого класса так и его суперкласса. Ничего странного.

Comment: Т.е. чего же ещё ожидать от вызова метода суперкласса? Вы же переопределяете поведение в своём(!) новом классе-наследнике. Родитель и потомок ведут себя как живые существа: если потомка не обучить новому - он действует КАК родитель. Но если потомка научить делать что-то по-новому - это не заставит родителя сменить поведение.

Comment: Говоря super.сделайЧтоТо() - мы просим конкретный экземпляр потомка сделать что-то ТАК ЖЕ, КАК и родитель.

Answer (score 14):

Во-первых завязывайте с такой терминологией, нет никаких внешних и внутренних объектов. У вас есть класс `Dog`, который расширяет класс `Animal`. Наследование представляет собой отношение типа является(is a). Следовательно в Вашем случае объект `Dog` является объектом `Animal`, а значит содержит в себе его поведение. Поведение родительского класса может использоваться в подклассе при помощи ключевого слова super, что Вы и продемонстрировали.

Ключевое слово `this` используется для получения объектом ссылки на самого себя, что в данном случае делается по-умолчанию. Т.е. Вы получите такой же результат если опустите его.

Чтобы лучше понять преимущества полиморфизма разберите паттерн проектирования "Стратегия". На мой взгляд один из самых ярких примеров.

Также если Вы пишете `Animal dog = new Dog();` Вы говорите машине: "Создай мне объект `Dog` и помести его в переменную типа `Animal`". Вы можете это сделать, поскольку `Dog` является `Animal`. Однако обращаясь к этой переменной у Вас будет вызываться метод класса `Dog` поскольку в ней содержится объект `Dog`. `Animal` здесь - это тип переменной, а не объекта.